# Confidence interval estimation from sample

Tags: confidence-interval

I have a sample of data that follows a certain distribution with known parameters. How can I estimate the confidence interval based on this sample, without using the quantile function?

Comment: Confidence interval ... for what quantity?

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain of the population distribution and its parameters, you are done. Why would you want to compute a confidence interval to quantify the uncertainty of an estimate from a sample, when you already know exactly the distribution of the population?